# Why are these formulas for the variance equal?

Tags: self-study, variance

[image]

I am trying to understand why the simple bootstrap procedure does not work, but for now I would like to know why we can we write $s^2_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i = 1} X^2_i - (\bar{X}_n)^2$ ?

This is a part of a paper by Liu and Singh (1992) *Moving blocks jackknifes and bootstrap capture weak dependence*.

Comment: This is a standard result, achieved with a few algebraic manipulations. You can check it by noting that both formulas for $s_n^2$ are invariant under permutations of the $X_i$, so it suffices to verify that the coefficients of $X_1^2$ and $X_1X_2$ are the same in both expressions.

Comment: If the value of whuber's comment isn't clear to you, take the first form, expand the square, and then simplify and collect terms.

Comment: $X_1 , X_2 \dots X_n$ are iid?

Comment: @Monolite the iid assumption does not matter for this question, which does not really deal with random variables--it's only about the variance formula.  (IID is needed to make sense of the assertion about convergence in the quoted material, though.)

Comment: $\sum_{i = 1}^n \bar{X}_n( -2X_j + \bar{X}) =   \bar{X}_n(-2n\bar{X}_n + n\bar{X}_n)$

Comment: @whuber Actually it is now my understanding that the Law of large numbers in the dependent identically distributed case + stationarity is being used.

Comment: @whuber after showing that $s^2_n$ converges to $Var_F(X_1) $ the author states that this is an inconsistency of the bootstrap procedure. Why? even if the r.v. are m-dependent they still have the same distribution, so where is the inconsistency?

Comment: I cannot answer that without seeing exactly what the author says.  But comments are no place for follow-up questions.  For informal discussions you can try our chat room or--this is probably better--you can formulate a new question about this inconsistency.